# Using chart.js, how do I align bars instead of centering them when there are only a few bars to display?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

As some background: I have a horizontal bar chart with a dynamic number of bars. I have set min and max bar widths for each of the datasets.

---

By default, chart.js aligns the bars in the center of chart. Instead I would like to align the bars to the left (or in the top as I am using a horizontal bar chart).

Thinking of the bars as HTML elements, this would be the equivalent of applying the css: `float:left` to each bar. Is there anyway to do this in chart.js? I still want the axes to extend to the end of the container, it just looks funny to have only a couple bars with a ton of space in between them (I also don't want really **fat** bars).

Thanks for any help!

---

Note: This is a duplicate of [56361398](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361398/align-the-bar-and-labels-using-chart-js)

---

**EDIT**: See [codepen](https://codepen.io/bigzmaster/pen/JjYQgVJ) for example (one bar is centered in the chart, I would like it aligned to the left, next to the y axis).

Comment: Could you provide an example of how it looks now? Try adding a codepen.io example.

Comment: @adelriosantiago Does the codepen help? There's a work around to just add more bars with 0 value, but that introduces other issues as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the settings and there is no setting to left-align the bar charts. I doubt it is easy to implement since Chart.JS is a `canvas` under the hood.

Also, technically speaking the chart is in fact "left-aligned" however it is just one slim bar. The bar could very well use the whole bar space in red:
[image]

The best workaround is to create empty `labels` that will later be populated if needed.
[image]
If you need to add more bars just check if a label name is `""` (empty) and then overwrite it. Otherwise `push` the new label.

Example: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/vYLYXPx?editors=0110

Comment: Thanks for the response @adelriosantiago. This is how I ended up solving the problem; sadly I have a dynamic number of categories (so I can calculate those based on container size), but on window resize I still have issues.
Looks like this is just a limitation of the library!